# Cannot read property something of undefined Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, sdk

I am not sure what I am trying to do has any logic yet giving it a try.

I am trying to add Veriff SDK in my Angular App.
The following error I get. Any help appreciated.

the .html

```
<button class="btn" [disabled]="isVerified"
                    (click)="myFn()">Finish</button>
```

The .ts file

```
export class myComponent(){
   isVerified : boolean = true;

ngOnInit() {

  const veriff = Veriff({
      host: 'https://stationapi.veriff.com',
      apiKey: '',
      parentId: 'veriff-root',
      onSession: function(err, response) {
        console.log(response.status)  //success
      window.veriffSDK.createVeriffFrame({ url: response.verification.url }); 
      if( response && response.status === 'success'){
        this.isVerified = !this.isVerified
      }
.....} //rest of the code is here
```

On ngOnInit() I call the Veriff api.

I am trying if response is success make disable false. But I am getting this Cannot read property 'isVerified' of undefined. How to fix this.

Comment: Use an arrow function to preserve the meaning of `this` to the outer scope: `onSession: (err, response) => { ... }`.

Comment: this worked! Can't imagine coding life without stack overflow! Thank you!.

Comment: Can you share the steps you took to configure Veriff with Angular ?  I am having an issue trying to integrate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use arrow functions (lambda expressions). Otherwise if you use `functions` it will change the meaning of `this`.

This should fix your issue:

```js
ngOnInit() {

  const veriff = Veriff({
      host: 'https://stationapi.veriff.com',
      apiKey: '',
      parentId: 'veriff-root',
      onSession: (err, response) => {
        console.log(response.status)  //success
      window.veriffSDK.createVeriffFrame({ url: response.verification.url }); 
      if( response && response.status === 'success'){
        this.isVerified = !this.isVerified
      }
.....} //rest of the code is here
```